# Mongodb, grouping values only once

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to mongodb, I have a collection of people and some of them have a value that I am interested in ("val"). For everyone who has that value, I would like to have a list of another value ("potential") without repeating.

```
{ "_id" : 001, "val" : true, "potential", 100}
{ "_id" : 002, "val" : true, "potential", 200}
{ "_id" : 003, "val" : true, "potential", 200}
{ "_id" : 004, "potential" : 300}
{ "_id" : 005, "potential" : 400}
```

I would like to get

```
{"values" : [100, 200]}
```

Thank you very much